# File Browser configuration error: name 'settings' is not defined

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-file-upload, django-filebrowser, django-2.1

I try to activate django-filebrowser-no-grappelli and I've use [this indications](https://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html) for its configuration.

Then I've updated setting.py with this:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'filebrowser',
    'tinymce',
    'app4test',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangosite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
                os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app4test/templates'),
            ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangosite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'it'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media-folder')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
                    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
                    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app4test/static'),
                ]

# django-tinymce4-lite config data
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'height': 360,
    'width': 1120,
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'modern',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2': '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'statusbar': True,
    }

# django-filebrowser-no-grappelli config data
DIRECTORY = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY", 'uploads/')

EXTENSIONS = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_EXTENSIONS", {
    'Image': ['.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.png','.tif','.tiff'],
    'Document': ['.pdf','.doc','.rtf','.txt','.xls','.csv'],
    'Video': ['.mov','.wmv','.mpeg','.mpg','.avi','.rm'],
    'Audio': ['.mp3','.mp4','.wav','.aiff','.midi','.m4p']
})

SELECT_FORMATS = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_SELECT_FORMATS", {
    'file': ['Image','Document','Video','Audio'],
    'image': ['Image'],
    'document': ['Document'],
    'media': ['Video','Audio'],
})

VERSIONS_BASEDIR = getattr(settings, 'FILEBROWSER_VERSIONS_BASEDIR', '_versions')

VERSIONS = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_VERSIONS", {
    'admin_thumbnail': {'verbose_name': 'Admin Thumbnail', 'width': 60, 'height': 60, 'opts': 'crop'},
    'thumbnail': {'verbose_name': 'Thumbnail (1 col)', 'width': 60, 'height': 60, 'opts': 'crop'},
    'small': {'verbose_name': 'Small (2 col)', 'width': 140, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
    'medium': {'verbose_name': 'Medium (4col )', 'width': 300, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
    'big': {'verbose_name': 'Big (6 col)', 'width': 460, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
    'large': {'verbose_name': 'Large (8 col)', 'width': 680, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
})

VERSION_QUALITY = getattr(settings, 'FILEBROWSER_VERSION_QUALITY', 90)

ADMIN_VERSIONS = getattr(settings, 'FILEBROWSER_ADMIN_VERSIONS', ['thumbnail', 'small', 'medium', 'big', 'large'])

ADMIN_THUMBNAIL = getattr(settings, 'FILEBROWSER_ADMIN_THUMBNAIL', 'admin_thumbnail')

VERSION_PROCESSORS = getattr(settings, 'FILEBROWSER_VERSION_PROCESSORS', [
    'filebrowser.utils.scale_and_crop',
])

VERSION_NAMER = getattr(settings, 'FILEBROWSER_VERSION_NAMER', 'filebrowser.namers.VersionNamer')

PLACEHOLDER = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_PLACEHOLDER", "")

SHOW_PLACEHOLDER = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_SHOW_PLACEHOLDER", False)

FORCE_PLACEHOLDER = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_FORCE_PLACEHOLDER", False)
```

But when I start the server I've this error:

> ....   File
>   "/var/www/html/dev/miosito/django/beautifulsite_v0.1/djangosite/djangosite/settings.py",
>   line 168, in 
>       DIRECTORY = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY", 'uploads/') NameError: name 'settings' is not defined

Honestly, for me isn't clear if all of the strings must be copied at the end of settings.py or in another part. I thing that this is the problem, I'm in confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are showing you how *they* find the settings from your config &/or what the respective defaults are. If you want to update your project's settings file to change some or all of the defaults, you should do something like

```
# settings.py

# FileBrowser settings
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = 'uploads/'
FILEBROWSER_EXTENSIONS = {
    'Image': ['.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.png','.tif','.tiff'],
    'Document': ['.pdf','.doc','.rtf','.txt','.xls','.csv'],
    'Video': ['.mov','.wmv','.mpeg','.mpg','.avi','.rm'],
    'Audio': ['.mp3','.mp4','.wav','.aiff','.midi','.m4p']
}
```